# Computing elements for an interactive quiz in amp-html

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I'm trying to build an interactive quiz with amp-html. The quiz would be just 3 questions with A, B, C and D as choices. By using `amp-selector` I can see which option (A, B, C or D) a user selects thanks to the additional `selected` class that's added to the element. So each quiz individually, I should have no problem setting it up.

However, once the user finishes selecting all 3 questions I want to have a reveal, but I am having difficulty finding a way to aggregate all the answers to the questions.

If I were able to do this with javascript, this would not be difficult obviously, but being limited to `amp-components` I'm not sure how to execute the last step of computing the answers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Put all questions into a single form. Once submitted, you can render the result returned from your server directly into the AMP page. [This sample](https://ampbyexample.com/samples_templates/poll/) demonstrates how to do this.
2. Evaluate the questions client side using amp-bind. The idea is to write the selected answers to amp-state and then calculate the aggregate answer based on the amp-state.

Here is a simple example (see it in action [here](https://jsbin.com/xozasijale/edit?html,output)):

```
<h2>Whats 1 + 1?</h2>
<amp-selector layout="container" on="select:AMP.setState({question1: event.targetOption})">
  <div option="a">1</div>
  <div option="b">2</div>
  <div option="c">3</div>
</amp-selector>
<h2>What's 1*1?</h2>
<amp-selector layout="container" on="select:AMP.setState({question2: event.targetOption})">
  <div option="a">1</div>
  <div option="b">2</div>
  <div option="c">3</div>
</amp-selector>

<div hidden [hidden]="!question1 || !question2">
  <div hidden [hidden]="question1 != 'b' || question2 != 'a'">
    Yay! All answers correct.
  </div>
  <div hidden [hidden]="question1 == 'b' && question2 == 'a'">
    Wrong answer! Please try again.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! I got this working, however I had to drop the singles quotes in the reveal prompts: `question1 == a`. This only happens with `==`? Turns out the single quotes were throwing a "default value for [hidden] does not match first expression". Any idea why this is?

Comment: dropping the single quotes is a bad idea as the expression no longer works (it takes `a` and `b` as unintialised variables). You can safely ignore the  "default value for [hidden] does not match first expression" warning in this case as it doesn't apply in your case.